# How do I define a function with an input array parameter

Tags: python, arrays, function, parameters

I want to create a function with one input array parameter and then return an array from 1st,4th and 6th element.

This is what I have came up with so far. So basically I want to print a,d,f

```
def something(paramOne):
    result = [paramOne[1,4,6]]
    return result

print(something(['a','b','c','d','e','f']))
```

Comment: Try `result = [paramOne[i-1] for i in [1,4,6]]`. `list` does not support multi indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension to pull out the elements you want.

```
def something(paramOne):
    select_list = [1,4,6]
    return [paramOne[i-1] for i in select_list]

print(something(['a','b','c','d','e','f']))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue: Index of any iterable should be an integer, you are giving a list

Fix: Going through the list and if the index(i+1 to make it 1 indexed) is in our list add it to the result

```
def something(paramOne):
    # result = [paramOne[1,4,6]] >>> Index of any iterable should be an integer, you are giving a list
    result = [v for i,v in enumerate(paramOne) if i+1 in [1,4,6]] # here i am going through the list and if the index(i+1 to make it 1 indexed) is in our list add it to the result
    return result

print(something(['a','b','c','d','e','f']))
```

```
['a', 'd', 'f']
```